# Как реализовать создание и проверку электронной цифровой подписи?

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать создание и проверку электронной цифровой подписи для файлов на основе алгоритма ГОСТ 34.10-2012, чтобы допустим в результате создания подписи, мы загружаем какой либо файл входной, а на выходе должны получить уже подписанный файл и чтобы к нему добавлялось ещё расширение sign. Принцип создания подписи я понял, но в интернете что то не могу найти пример для файлов. Интерфейс приложения выглядит следующим образом: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Взять описание алгоритма и закодить. Или готовую библиотеку.

Comment: Существует ли описание данного алгоритма?

Comment: @EllaSvetlaya, разумеется существует - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%9E%D0%A1%D0%A2_%D0%A0_34.10-2012

Comment: @Nofate а, ну тогда да, берем алгоритм и пишем, т.к. готовых я не встречала. Судя по алгоритму, не так уж всё и сложно...

Comment: @EllaSvetlaya В самом верху списка вещей, которые никогда не нужно делать, есть запрет на реализацию алгортмов шифрования на коленке.

Comment: Андрей, вы нашли хоть одну библиотеку, реализующую алгоритм, которая вас удовлетворяет?

Comment: Не могу найти, я искал информацию в интернете, но так понятного ничего не нашёл

Comment: Предлагаю порыться на гитхабе в готовых реализациях: https://github.com/search?l=C%23&q=gost&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: @EllaSvetlaya Не сложный алгоритм? Я например не могу сходу понять как выглядит даже график кривой, которой там используется, основываясь только на выражении для инварианта `J(E)` из этой стати. Или откуда там коэфициент 1728=24^2+24^2+24^2? Что такого особенного в этом числе, что оно там оказалось?

Comment: а в visual studio библиотек по гост нет или есть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/polarnik/Tools.CMSCreator

```
byte[] documentContent = ReadFile(fileLoc);
byte[] signContent = Sign(x509Certificate2, documentContent, true);
string signPath = fileLoc + ".sign";
WriteFile(signPath, signContent);
```

функция подписания:

```
    public byte[] Sign(X509Certificate2 certificate, byte[] data, bool detached)
    {
        // то что подписываем
        var contentInfo = new ContentInfo(data);
        var signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo, detached);
        // сертификат для подписания

        var cmsSigner = new CmsSigner(SubjectIdentifierType.IssuerAndSerialNumber, certificate);
        signedCms.ComputeSignature(cmsSigner, true);
        // подпись
        return signedCms.Encode();
    }
```

Чтобы работало установите криптопровайдер, реализующий ГОСТ. Например VipNET, LissyCSP, CryptoPro, ... Создайте ключ и сертификат. Далее криптовайдер всё сделает сам, работать с сертификатом будете через стандартное API. Никаких отличий между ГОСТ/не ГОСТ для CryptoAPI нет.

Есть также Bouncy Castle. Вижу в интерфейсе есть кнопка "Создать ключи". Если будете выпускать не самоподписанные сертификаты, а программировать их выдачу, то понадобится Bouncy Castle. Для самодписанных хватит возможностей CryptoAPI.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое за помощь